# Using optional arguments in numba

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to speed up a function by compiling it using [numba](https://numba.pydata.org/)

```
@jit(nopython=True)
def test_func(x, y = None, z = None):
    if y is None:
        return x
    elif y is not None:
        return x * 2 + y * 2
    else:
        return x * 2 + z * 2
```

When I run the following code

```
x1 = 1.0
y1 = 2.0
z1 = 3.0

print(test_func(x1))
print(test_func(x1, y = y1))
print(test_func(x1, z = z1))
```

The first function output is printed

```
1.0
```

and I get an error message saying

```
    print(test_func(x1, y = y1))
    raise e.with_traceback(None)

numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline(step: nopython frontend) 
No implementation of function Function( < built - in function mul >) found for signature:
 >>> mul(none, Literal[int](2))
    
...
...


def test_func(x, y = None, z = None):
    <source elided>
    else:
        return x * 2 + z * 2
        ^
```

If I understand this error correctly, it's saying that it can't multiply a Nonetype object with an integer object, and that the error is found in the

```
else:
    return x * 2 + z * 2
```

part of the code. I have the following questions about numba's behaviour in this case:

**Questions:**

1. Why does numba only start worrying about the `else` condition in the `test_func()` when the function is called with an optional argument, e.g. `test_func(x1, y = y1)`, and not when it's called without any optional arguments, e.g., `test_func(x1)`? I don't have a lot of experience with compiling, but I would expect numba to throw an error immediately when the function is compiled for the first time. I find it weird that the first call to the function, `test_func(x)`, is printed.
2. Passing the second optional argument `y` should only trigger the second `if` condition. Why do we get an error regarding the `else` statement?
3. What would be the best way of passing optional arguments in this case? I have looked around in [documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/types.html) at the `optional` signature, but I didn't manage to get it working.

**Note:** I have figured out that making sure that `z` is not `None` when the third statement might be triggered fixes the error. If I change the test function to

```
def test_func(x, y = None, z = None):
    if y is None:
        return x
    elif y is not None:
        return x * 2 + y * 2
    elif z is not None:
        return x * 2 + z * 2
```

I don't get any errors. However, I would like to understand how to properly do this with numba, as the last `elif` in the function above should really be an `else`.

Comment: Have you tried defining the argument types in `numba`s decorator? I think it will have to compile another version of the function when you call it the second time, because it didn't have to account for more arguments the first time. Also, what if you defined `y` and `z` to default `0` instead of None ?

Comment: Hey Trevis. Yes I have tried defining the arguments as I mentioned in point 3, but I didn't manage to get it working (I'm more interested in why numba is behaving in this way). While setting the optional arguments to `0` removes the error, it's not a stable solution as it's possible that 0 is a value that would be passed to the function.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71225435/why-am-i-getting-isinstance-cannot-determine-numba-type/71226126#71226126) new (late) post help to understand the problem?