# Why am I getting 'isinstance': Cannot determine Numba type?

Tags: numba

I am new with Numba. I am trying to accelerate a pretty complicated solver. However, I keep getting an error such as

`numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Untyped global name 'isinstance': Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'builtin_function_or_method'>`

I wrote a small example to reproduce the same error:

```
import numba
import numpy as np
from numba import types
from numpy import zeros_like, isfinite
from numpy.linalg import solve
from numpy.random import uniform


@numba.njit(parallel=True)
def foo(A_, b_, M1=None, M2=None):
    x_ = zeros_like(b_)
    r = b_ - A_.dot(x_)
    flag = 1

    if isinstance(M1, types.NoneType):           # Error here
        y = r
    else:
        y = solve(M1, r)
        if not isfinite(y).any():
            flag = 2

    if isinstance(M2, types.NoneType):
        z = y
    else:
        z = solve(M2, y)
        if not isfinite(z).any():
            flag = 2

    return z, flag


N = 10

tmp = np.random.rand(N, N)
A = np.dot(tmp, tmp.T)

x = np.zeros((N, 1), dtype=np.float64)
b = np.vstack([uniform(0.0, 1.0) for i in range(N)])

X_1, info = foo(A, b)
```

Also if I change the decorator to `generated_jit()` I get the following error:

```
r = b_ - A_.dot(x_)
AttributeError: 'Array' object has no attribute 'dot'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numba **compiles** the function and requires every variables to be **statically typed**. This means that each variable has only one unique type: one variable cannot be of both the type `NoneType` and something else as opposed to with CPython based on dynamic typing. Dynamic typing is also a major source of the slowdown of CPython. Thus, using `isinstance` in nopython JITed Numba functions does not make much sense. In fact, this built-in function is not supported.

That being said, Numba supports [optional arguments](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/types.html#optional-types) by **specifying `optional(ArgumentType)` in the signature** (note that the resulting type of the variable is `optional(ArgumentType)` and not `ArgumentType` nor `NoneType`. You can then test if the argument is set using `if yourArgument is None:`. I do not know what is the type of `M1` and `M2` in your code but they need to be explicitly defined in the signature with optional argument.

Comment: Great answer, as practical tip for an implementation. Use the jit on the actual number crunching where the types are usually well known and write normal python functions as wrappers to check the inputs and operating mode. These checks should not be the bottleneck.